# Convert DateTime to Date

Tags: apex, datetime, date

I want to Convert `DateTime` into `Date`

I have been trying this out ..below is the code snippet

```
public void searchSFDC() {
    DateTime lastModDate ;
    for(sObject resultSet : searchResults[0]) { // searching only solutions
        SfResults sf = new SfResults();
        lastModDate=Datetime.valueOf(resultSet.get('LastModifiedDate'));
        sf.lastModifiedDate = date.newinstance(lastModDate.year(),lastModDate.month(),lastModDate.day());
     }
}
public class SfResults {
        public Date lastModifiedDate {get;set;}     
}
```

But `sf.lastModifiedDate` is shown as **2014-04-11 00:00:00**  .I do not want the 00:00:00 timestamp .How can we achieve this?

Comment: Where is it shown, on the page?

Answer (score 28):

Datetime objects have this [date](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_date) method:

> date()
>
> Returns the Date component of a Datetime in the local time zone of the
> context user.

so your code can use it like this:

```
Datetime dt = (Datetime) resultSet.get('LastModifiedDate');
sf.lastModifiedDate = dt.date();
```

(Generally you would need a null check in the code but as `LastModifiedDate` always has a value here you don't.)

So this gets you the correct `Date` object value. But an answer is needed to mast0r's question to cover how to get the final presentation right.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
DateTime dt = Acc.CreatedDate;
integer year = dt.year();
integer month = dt.month();
integer day = dt.day();
```