# Custom Field Data type converting to DateTime in Apex Collection

Tags: apex, list, date

I have a custom field with data type "Date" and when I run a query in the dev console the date returns as expected

```
SELECT customfield_date__d from myobject

2017-10-03
```

When I query against the custom object using a List in Apex the field in the List is now in DateTime

```
List<myobject> myrows = [SELECT customfield_date__d from myobject]
```

Debug log

```
VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[62]|myrows|"2017-10-03T00:00:00.000Z"
```

If I display the field in the log (system.debug()), the results is strange; the "T" and ".000Z" are removed

```
system.debug(myrows[0].customfield_date__d);

2017-10-04 00:00:00
```

I'm not exactly clear on all the conversion going on, but the result I need is the custom field in date format

```
2017-10-03
```

I need to compare the date to 60 days ago for all the rows in myobject and with all these conversions I"m getting stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: what is your current approach? where is your code? where re you stuck? as is, this might be a possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime to Date](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32840/convert-datetime-to-date)

Answer (score 1):

It's really just how the system behaves. `Date` values are just `DateTime` values with a midnight component, and that's how the system debugs `Date` values (via `String.valueOf(Date)`). They all mean exactly the same thing. If you want to compare to sixty days ago, just get a date:

```
Date sixtyDaysAgo = Date.today().addDays(-60);
if(sixtyDaysAgo > myrows[0].customfield_date__c) {
    // was more than sixty days ago
} else {
    // sixty or less days ago
}
```