# How do I change the date format in apex?

Tags: apex

I have written an apex class which calls an API and it returns a response. One of the values in the response is a string value representing date and time. The date time is in the format 2022-08-28T12:35:30 format for example. I just want the 2022-08-28 part and display it in the format 08-28-2022. How do I do that?
If I store the response in the variable "Update time" then would it be

Date Update Time = response.format()?
Can someone please help me convert 2022-08-28T12:35:30 to 08-28-2022 ? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert DateTime to Date](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32840/convert-datetime-to-date)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use the standardized ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-dd)? Also, _where_ are you trying to display this date (is stored in an SObject field and displayed on the page layout? is it on a visualforce page/LWC?)

Answer (score 1):

We can't change the way the date is represented in the Date class, but we can format it a certain way when we convert to a string. This can be accomplished with the [Datetime class `format()` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format)':

```java
String formatted = response.format('MM-dd-yyyy');
```

Answer (score -2):

here is the updated code:

```
String response = '2022-08-28T12:35:30';
response = response.replace('T' , ' ' );
DateTime myDate= Date.valueof(response);
String dateStr = myDate.format('MM-dd-yyyy') ;
System.debug('dateis'+dateStr);
```

Comment: One problem i just noticed that the response is a string text which is in a date format. so i need to take the string 2022-08-29T12:00:07 and remove the T

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: @user3688231 can you provide the response you are getting in String?